# How do I diagnose/check USB HDD read breakdowns?

Tags: linux, hard-drive, command-line, fsck, portable-harddrive

I have a Seagate Backup Plus portable drive.

Recently, reading from it has started to break down. It makes tick-like noises, and apparently retries stuff. My dmesg log has this kind of messages:

```
[451192.130101] scsi host6: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
[451222.562724] scsi host6: uas_eh_device_reset_handler start
[451222.563331] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 2 inflight: CMD 
[451222.563335] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#2 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 88 04 00 00 01 00
[451222.563339] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#3 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 3 inflight: CMD 
[451222.563342] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#3 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 88 05 00 00 01 00
[451222.563345] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 4 inflight: CMD 
[451222.563346] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 88 02 00 00 01 00
[451222.563349] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#1 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 5 inflight: CMD 
[451222.563351] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#1 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 88 01 00 00 01 00
[451222.563354] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#4 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 6 inflight: CMD 
[451222.563356] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#4 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 88 03 00 00 01 00
[451222.563359] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#5 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 7 inflight: CMD 
[451222.563361] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#5 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 88 07 00 00 01 00
[451222.563364] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#6 uas_zap_pending 0 uas-tag 8 inflight: CMD 
[451222.563366] sd 6:0:0:0: [sdd] tag#6 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 e8 e0 88 06 00 00 01 00
[451222.691086] usb 1-9: reset high-speed USB device number 38 using xhci_hcd
[451222.845722] scsi host6: uas_eh_device_reset_handler success
```

and unmounting, waiting, re-mounting and re-reading sometimes works, sometimes doesn't. Running fsck results in the same hiccups/breakdown, takes a whole lot of time and gets stuck.

What should I do in order to better diagnose the problem?

Answer (score 2):

*It doesn't matter what the cause it. Back up all data on this disk (I'd hope you have a proper backup that isn't on a portable drive) **RIGHT NOW***

Now that's covered, it looks like commands are timing out while running and the bus is resetting. This, along with the 'ticking' noise, is indicative of failure of the USB drive hardware.

There is a possibility that it's not the drive dying at all, and could either be a problem with the usb hub that it's connected to (hub in this sense in the hardware that runs your usb port on the computer) or even the psu if it has a seperate one, but it's more likely to be the hardware itself in my experience.

Comment: Wouldn't running a S.M.A.R.T test also be recommended?  First, garnish current info: `smartctl -a /dev/sdd`, then running an extended test `smartctl -t long /dev/sdd`.  Once completed, `smartctl -a /dev/sdd` again and review data/errors.

Comment: By the time it's ticking you're way past SMART & into **replace right now** while you still have the chance. You're possibly also into 'don't power it off in case it won't spin up again'.

Answer (score 1):

Ticking disk is dying disk.

Replace immediately.